# Firefox about:config reset

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I've been troubleshooting my website and I changed a couple of settings in my firefox about:config. I changed the following settings,

[image]

And now I get a ton of these errors on my site,

[image]

These errors were not present before I made the changes to my about:config so I would just like to reset everything back. I've tried just about every solution I could find online. I've uninstalled the browser and deleted the Firefox folder under %APPDATA%, that didn't work. I've reset the page and I've even tried putting the values of those settings back to what they originally were.

Here is a screen shot of the original values before I changed them,

[image]

A weird thing to point out is the *security.tls.version.fallback-limit* was not present before the changes were made.

Comment: about:config is store with firefox profile, I can't remember if this is store with a .js format, if you have delete %appdata%\firefox the profile should be cleaned. May be you can try again to clean firefox profile via [GUI option](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings)?

Comment: I actually tried that link first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe these warnings result not from the settings you have modified, but from an automatic update, which you probably didn't notice. All major browsers cease support for SHA-1 certificates, and [so does Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2014/09/23/phasing-out-certificates-with-sha-1-based-signature-algorithms/).

You can try to [install an older version of Firefox](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/) to confirm my guess.